# Prevent indexing of images containing a given string

Tags: robots.txt

I am a photographer and I need to prevent the indexing ( thus the finding ) of the images of my clients that are displayed on a password protected shop.
I could include in the file names a specific string like ...  WWWWW    ... that would mark the files I want to hide.
Does this robots.txt do the work ?

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /*WWWWW*
```

How can I test if it does ?
Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance.

Answer (score 0):

```
User-agent: Googlebot-Image
Disallow: /*.gif$
```

or you can totally disable with the help of htaccess file.

```
Deny from all
```

Comment: Did you read the question ? ...  the whole question ?

Answer (score 0):

You can test your existing `robots.txt` file by using for example https://en.ryte.com/free-tools/robots-txt/ or even Googles own tester https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062598?hl=en

---

The following will disallow a specific directory:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /path/to/images/
```

You can also use an wildcard `*`:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /*.jpg         # Disallows any JPEG images
Disallow: /*/images/     # Disallows parsing of all */images/* directories
```

*There's no need for trailing wildcards, they are ignored. `/*/path/*` equals `/*/path/`.*

You don't want to make a extensive list of every single file to disallow, because the contents of the `robots.txt` file is publicly available. Therefore it is good practice to prioritize directories over file paths.

See https://developers.google.com/search/reference/robots_txt#url-matching-based-on-path-values for examples of paths/wildcards, and what they actually match.